# Object with collection containing Serializable, non-primitive objects can't be set as ActiveMQ ObjectMessage

Tags: java, serialization, collections, jms, activemq-classic

I'd appreciate any help on this...

I have an Object I'm trying to send in a JMS ObjectMessage by calling setObject. This Object contains a HashMap<String, Object> content as well as some other fields. When the map contains primitive elements the message is built fine. Likewise if I add a non-primitive serializable field to the Object it also sends ok.

Here's the rub: Whenever I try to add a serializable non-primitive object to the MAP I get the following MessageFormatException:

```
javax.jms.MessageFormatException: Only objectified primitive objects, String, 
Map and List types are allowed but was: com.abc.ObjectInList
```

The javadoc for ObjectMessage specifies...

> Only Serializable Java objects can be used.

... check. And ...

> If a collection of Java objects must be sent, one of the Collection classes provided since JDK 1.2 can be used.

... double check. While this doesn't specifically say anything about Serializable objects in a Collection, I guess I would assume this would be supported. Am I doing something wrong here? Do I just bite the bullet and make a new field in my top level Object so I don't have to put it in the Collection?

Using ActiveMQ 5.2. A pertinent Stack Trace follows.

```
2011-08-01 21:06:05,767 ERROR     javax.jms.MessageFormatException: Only objectified primitive objects, String, Map and List types are allowed but was: com.abc.engine.ejb.BasicSchedule@58f295b9 type: class com.abc.engine.ejb.BasicSchedule
2011-08-01 21:06:05,767 ERROR          at org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQMessage.checkValidObject(ActiveMQMessage.java:468)
2011-08-01 21:06:05,767 ERROR          at org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQMapMessage.setObject(ActiveMQMapMessage.java:705)
2011-08-01 21:06:05,767 ERROR          at com.abc.chronicle.ejb.ChronicleMessageBean.initMessage(ChronicleMessageBean.java:149)
2011-08-01 21:06:05,767 ERROR          at com.abc.chronicle.ejb.ChronicleMessageBean.send(ChronicleMessageBean.java:125)
2011-08-01 21:06:05,767 ERROR          at com.abc.chronicle.ejb.ChronicleMessageBean.onMessage(ChronicleMessageBean.java:77)
2011-08-01 21:06:05,767 ERROR          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)2011-08-01 21:06:05,768 ERROR          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
2011-08-01 21:06:05,777 ERROR [com.abc.chronicle.ejb.ChronicleMessageBean]   JMS Exception Sending Message to SDK.OUTGOING_NOTIFICATION : javax.jms.MessageFormatException: Only objectified primitive objects, String, Map and List types are allowed but was: com.abc.engine.ejb.BasicSchedule@1003b2df type: class com.abc.engine.ejb.BasicSchedule
2011-08-01 21:06:05,778 ERROR     javax.jms.MessageFormatException: Only objectified primitive objects, String, Map and List types are allowed but was: com.abc.engine.ejb.BasicSchedule@1003b2df type: class com.abc.engine.ejb.BasicSchedule
2011-08-01 21:06:05,778 ERROR          at org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQMessage.checkValidObject(ActiveMQMessage.java:468)
2011-08-01 21:06:05,778 ERROR          at org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQMapMessage.setObject(ActiveMQMapMessage.java:705)
2011-08-01 21:06:05,778 ERROR          at com.abc.chronicle.ejb.ChronicleMessageBean.initMessage(ChronicleMessageBean.java:149)
2011-08-01 21:06:05,778 ERROR          at com.abc.chronicle.ejb.ChronicleMessageBean.send(ChronicleMessageBean.java:125)
2011-08-01 21:06:05,778 ERROR          at com.abc.chronicle.ejb.ChronicleMessageBean.onMessage(ChronicleMessageBean.java:77)
```

Comment: I have that same problem too. I posted a test program here on the Camel forum: http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/MessageFormatException-using-requestBody-InOut-over-activemq-JMS-td5554469.html#a5711703. Is there a fix for this bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although I haven't checked it, but looking at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.activemq/activemq-core/5.2.0/org/apache/activemq/command/ActiveMQMessage.java#ActiveMQMessage.checkValidObject%28java.lang.Object%29) it seems like you hit this exception when ActiveMQ validates message **properties**, not the body. The [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/jms/ObjectMessage.html) for `ObjectMessage` reads:

> Only Serializable Java objects can be used.

I used all sorts of Java objects with ActiveMQ (arbitrary complex) and it always worked. However when you set message properties ([Message#setObjectProperty](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/jms/Message.html#setObjectProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29)):

> Note that this method works only for the objectified primitive object types (`Integer`, `Double`, `Long` ...) and `String` objects.

Inspecting the ActiveMQ codebase quoted above it looks like you are trying to use message object properties to send complex Java objects. This abuses the concept of message properties, which should be simple metadata like ids or peer names.

Also it looks like ActiveMQ optionally supports `Map` and `List`, but it this is vendor specific.

Comment: There is a Message.setObjectProperty(Object) in the Message interface, however, I am using the subclass ObjectMessage and the method [setObject](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/jms/ObjectMessage.html#setObject(java.io.Serializable))

Comment: Additionally, all of the Objects I am using extend Serializable

Comment: OK, can you add the stacktrace of this `MessageFormatException` to your question? I cannot reason just looking at the ActiveMQ codebase anymore.

Comment: thanks for taking a look - included the trace in the question (sorry for the formatting)

Comment: How does line 149 in `ChronicleMessageBean` look like in your code? I have a reason to believe that you are using `MapMessage` instead of `ObjectMessage`. Also seems like you are using slightly different version than 5.2.0, but that's not important. Are you sure you have created `ObjectMessage`?

Comment: Aha! You're absolutely right, I can't believe I was so foolish. Sorry to make you debug my code. Thanks a ton!